# Como desabilitar o botão no Angular?

Tags: angular

Observem bem o formulário

```
    <form #registerForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(registerForm)" class="col-lg-10" >
        <p>
          <label >Nome</label>
          <input type="text"  name="name" #name="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="user.name"  class="form-control" required/>
            <span *ngIf="!name.valid && name.touched">
              O nome é obrigatório
            </span>
        </p>
        <p>
          <label >Sobrenome</label>
          <input type="text"  name="surname" #surname="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="user.surname" class="form-control" required/>
            <span *ngIf="!surname.valid && surname.touched">
              O sobrenome é obrigatório
            </span>
        </p>
        <p>
          <label >Email</label>
          <input type="text"  name="email" #email="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="user.email" class="form-control" required/>
            <span *ngIf="!email.valid && email.touched">
              O email é obrigatório
            </span>
        </p>
        <p>
          <label>Senha</label>
          <input type="text"  name="password" #password="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="user.password" class="form-control" required/>
              <span *ngIf="!password.valid && password.touched">
                A senha é obrigatório
              </span>
        </p>
        <input type="submit" value="{{title}}" class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="!registerForm.form.valid" />
    </form>
</div>
```

Porque será que o botão **registro** não ficou desabilitado?

Para saber o valor do **!registerForm.form.valid** se ele está verdadeiro ou false eu fiz o seguinte ...

No arquivo de componente eu coloquei assim;

```
onSubmit(form: NgForm) {

    console.log(form);

  }
```

E verifiquei no console como estaria se estivesse assim;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E submeti o formulário e deu isso;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O atributo **valid** estava como **true** sabendo que deveria está como **false**

Onde será que está errado?

Comment: verificou se a condição `registerForm.form.valid` está retornando `false`?

Comment: como faço para saber?

Comment: se eu deixa assim ele fica desabilitado registerForm.form.valid mas se eu deixar assim ele fica habilitado !registerForm.form.valid

Comment: será que precisa de algum modulo para instalar?

Comment: essa pagina está com erros, já reparo?

Comment: desculpe a página não está com erro, eu copiei e colei sua sugestão no meu projeto e não funcionou.

Comment: Não há nada de errado em seu form, veja: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-p8jtmw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: O que eu indicaria é verificar se há algo no seu console com erro.

Comment: não há erro no consoles

Comment: eu fiz uma atualização da postagem, poderia dá uma olhada por favor?

Comment: @wladyband você tem a variável `user` definida em seu `ts`?

Comment: tenho sim, ele está no meu projeto

Comment: Que estranho eu fiz testes onlline e tudo funciona.

Comment: @Marconi poderia dá uma olhada, esse é meu projeto

https://github.com/wladyband/epui

Comment: https://github.com/wladyband/epui/blob/master/src/app/registro/registro/registro.component.html

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77943/discussion-between-marconi-and-wladyband).

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77946/discussion-on-question-by-wladyband-como-desabilitar-o-botao-no-angular)

Answer (score 1):

Você esta misturando [template forms](https://angular.io/guide/forms) com [reactive forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms)

Aqui tem uma [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9a5s8z) de como seria

Vou te mostrar como seria o codigo com o reactive forms:

```
<form [formGroup]="registerForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" class="col-lg-10" >
        <p>
          <label >Nome</label>
          <input type="text"  name="name"  class="form-control" formControlName="name"/>
            <span  *ngIf="name.invalid && (name.dirty || name.touched)">
              O nome é obrigatório
            </span>
        </p>
        <p>
          <label >Sobrenome</label>
          <input type="text"name="surname" formControlName="surname"  class="form-control" />
            <span *ngIf="!surname.valid && surname.touched">
              O sobrenome é obrigatório
            </span>
        </p>
        <p>
          <label >Email</label>
          <input type="text"  name="email" formControlName="email" class="form-control" />
            <span *ngIf="!email.valid && email.touched">
              O email é obrigatório
            </span>
        </p>
        <p>
          <label>Senha</label>
          <input type="text"  name="password" class="form-control"  formControlName="password" />
              <span *ngIf="!password.valid && password.touched">
                A senha é obrigatório
              </span>
        </p>
        <input type="submit" value="{{title}}" class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="registerForm.invalid" />
    </form>
</div>
```

NO ts

```
registerForm:FormGroup;
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder)

ngOnInit() {
    this.createForm()
}

createForm() {
    this.registerForm = this.fb.group({
        name: [ '', Validators.required], //Os nomes dentro do form control names tem que ser iguais a estes.
        surname: [ '', Validators.required],
        email: ['', Validators.required],
        password: ['', Validators.required]
    });
}


get name() { return this.registerForm.get('name'); }
get surname() { return this.registerForm.get('surname'); }
get email() { return this.registerForm.get('email'); }
get password() { return this.registerForm.get('password'); }
```

Comment: não resolveu, deu essa mensagem de erro no console

Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'. ("

Comment: compiler.js:486 Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'. ("


    <form [ERROR ->][formGroup]="registerForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" class="col-lg-10" >
        <p>
          <label >"): ng:///RegistroModule/RegistroComponent.html@4:10
No provider for ControlContainer ("


    [ERROR ->]<form [formGroup]="registerForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" class="col-lg-10" >
        <

Comment: você chegou a testar esse código antes de me passar?

Comment: Criei um stackblitz pra vc ver.

Comment: @wladyband deu certo?

Comment: eu não fiz nenhuma alteração, somente reiniciei o computador e voltou a funcionar, mas do jeito que você colocou também funciona.

Answer (score 1):

O interessante seria utilizar `formGroup`, que seu código `HTML` ficaria bem mais legível, mas para resolver seu problema baseado no que está expondo, então é só informar de qual formulário você está se referindo, por que "***registerForm***" é seu fomulário, mas você está colocando "***registerForm.form***", então perceba como poderá dar certo abaixo:

Seu `input` atualmente:

```
<input type="submit" value="{{title}}" class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="!registerForm.form.valid" />
```

Como seu `input` deve ficar:

```
<input type="submit" value="{{title}}" class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="!registerForm.valid" />
```

Pronto, caso seu problema não tenha solucionado ainda, então poderá verificar exatamente o que estava faltando.